STM32 Interfacing with Mission planner/Qground
I want to connect my custom stm32f405 to my mission planner like (pixhawk connecting with misssion planner) and see my mpu6050 data on the visual screen of mission planner. Any suggestion or refernece link for this? is this practically possible if i use esp32 module as a serial bridge linking my stm32 with the mission planner using the Udp connection?
i have simply tried to establish a udp connection and connect my stm32f405 with the uart pin of esp32 (rx2,tx2) and connect it with my mission planner on the desired port it shows nopp heartbeat received
